# Children's/YA fantasy book where the protagonist starts in a maze and figures out how to climb atop the maze walls in order to see exit

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read this book in the mid-1980s as a child myself from a Texas elementary school library. I seem to recall the protagonist beginning a long journey possibly with food provisions (cheese?) that begins in a maze. The maze seems endless but at some stage, they decide to climb a wall and can see the full maze from above in order to get to the exit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the approximate age and sex of the protagonist?

Comment: A male teenager, maybe 16?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be *[The Maze in the Heart of the Castle](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?228853)* by Dorothy Gilman. First published in 1983, it would be consistent with you reading it in the mid 80s. It deals with a 16 year old boy named Colin, traversing a magical maze. From the cover blurb:

> His name was Colin, and although he still couldn't believe it, his
> parents were gone, both dead from the plague. Scared, confused, and
> angry, he sought out a monk who told him about a haunted castle on
> Rheembeck Mountain -- and the old, strange wizard who lived there.
> Perhaps there Colin would find a way to stop his pain....
>
> But instead of answers, the wizard showed him a locked oak door.
> Beyond it lay an ancient stone maze that led to a mystical land, a
> place where bandits roamed freely, where people lived within dark
> caves, afraid of the light, where cruelty was the way of the world,
> and where beautiful girls were not always what they seemed.
>
> The wizard opened the oak door and invited Colin to enter. If Colin
> came through this strange place alive, he might indeed be able to ease
> the pain in his heart. But once inside, there could be no going
> back....

When he reaches the centre, he has to find the way out again, and he has the idea of climbing the walls:

> Colin said instead, thoughtfully, "Has anyone ever tried climbing to
> the top of that wall to look for a way out of the maze?"...
>
> From this height the walls of the maze stretched out like a giant
> honeycomb a mile or more on all sides of him.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I just found it on OpenLibrary too so I'll have a read, but that certainly sounds like it!

Comment: Interestingly, this book was first described as having been written by a character in Gilman's mystery novel, *The Tightrope Walker* (1979) where a plot summery and a number of quotes from it are given. Four years later the book *The Maze in the Heart of the Castle* was published. It does not follow the description in the earlier novel in all points, but does in many.